# Клиент-серверное приложение на Android

Tags: android

Необходимо написать клиент-серверное приложение на Android. А именно должна быть БД к которой пользователи будут подключаться через клиента и вводить данные, получать их, делать какие-то отчеты.. Узко специализированная программа, где будут размещаться заказы людьми. Какие-то готовые решения есть для реализации удаленной БД? Например можно ли в FireBase создать базу и все это реализовать там?

Comment: Можно через firebase, можно сделать свой сервер и общаться с БД через API... Вариантов множество. Смотрите что будет именно вам удобней для работы.

Answer (score 0):

Советую посмотреть хотя бы такое видео, здесь подробно объясняют что представляет из себя firebase.Если вы хотите написать приложение в короткие сроки , и у вашего приложения будет не большой оборот пользователей , то это весьма удобный инструмент

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mRmHqz0-W8&ab_channel=Google%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0

Здесь вы можете почитать про плюсы и минусы использования Firebase
https://habr.com/ru/company/livetyping/blog/320040/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю.